# What does $p$ mean in the energy-momentum relation?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum, notation

Suppose I have several particles each with some momentum vector $\mathbf{\vec p}_i$, what is $p$ in the relation $$E^2 = E_0^2 + (pc)^2$$
Is it the magnitude of the vector sum of all $\mathbf{\vec p}_i$ vectors?

Comment: Hint: What's $$\sum_i\mathbf{\vec p}_i$$ in the centre of mass frame?

Comment: @PM2Ring Hint: Fully relativistic 'center of mass frame'  is often called 'the center of momentum frame'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a system of $t=1,2,3,\dots, n$ particles, the energy-momentum relation will be written as follows:

$$\left( \sum_i^n E_i \right)^2 = \left( \sum_i^n c \vec{\mathbf p}_i \right)^2 + \left(M_0c^2\right)^2$$

The $\displaystyle \sum_i^n E_i$ term is the sum of the total energies of each particle, and the $\displaystyle \sum_i^n c \vec{\mathbf p}_i$ is the vector sum of momentum multiplied by the speed of light.  And, once squared, this becomes the magnitude squared of the total momentum multiplies by $c$.

Note that $M_0$ is the invariant mass, and is not equal to the sum of all the masses of the particles (unless the momentum of each particle at that time is zero).